# Submit form without change Include file variables PHP

Tags: php, forms, variables, post, include

I have a little problem with my script. I need to do a post form because I need to retrieve the "selected" option from my form, but in this page I included another important page, that contains some important variable that I also need after the Post form... What is the best way to avoid this problem?

Comment: post code, ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would be nice if you post some code, but based on what i understand you have 2 options:

1. save this variable on a $_SESSION and just use it wherever you need
2. you can put this var into your form as hidden

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="myVar" value="myValue" />
   ```

if this var is an array, use this:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="myVar[]" value="myValue" />
    <input type="hidden" name="myVar[]" value="myValue2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="myVar[]" value="myValue3" />
    <input type="hidden" name="myVar[]" value="myValue4" />
```

Comment: I just tried the second one, but the variable that I need is an Array and this didn't work...

Comment: @franksmith check the edition

Comment: What is better? Session or using the hidden input?

Comment: @franksmith if this array is not part of the form data, i think is better if you use $_SESSION

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could write it into a function, they use local scope and won't effect other variables outside the function. But show some code, so we could better understand what you're exactly meaning

Comment: I try to explain my problem better:
I have the page "test1.php" that include the "required.php" page.
The page "test1.php" edit some variables from the included page, but beyond that it contains a Form that I need to extract the value of a select/dropdown option... But if I do the Post for retrieve the value, all previous variables edited in the included page will be canceled...